# Does flutter WidgetTester test with keyboard showing?

Tags: android, flutter

I've recently come across what I assume is a bug where the WidgetTester.tap() method in flutter misses the button and because "behind some other widget", but I know for a fact that my widget has nothing above it.

That got me wondering, if I was to make the widget scrollable (its a numpad) and then ask the tester to scroll until the button is within view, would that fix the issue? I tried this out and surprisingly it worked.

So now I'm left here wondering why exactly it is missing the button, and why does it hit it correctly if I scroll the button into view? The only thing I can think of is that maybe the tester has the keyboard open? so I loaded the emulator and opened up a keyoard and there it is... the keyboard is basically covering what I expected.

[keyboard covering the numpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hItM.png)

For context, the top buttons of the numpad (1,2,3,4,5,6) all work and those buttons are not covered if the keyboard is open.

Now the question is does the flutter "tester" have the keyboard open when its running? If so, how can I disable it?

Thanks!